# Should I use async / await for REST GET calls?

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous

I'm trying to learn best practices for use of async / await in REST services hosted in ASP.NET. I've included an example below. In this case I have a GET request handler that pulls all accounts asynchronously. I've added an artificially large delay in the private method used to pull data by calling Task.Delay. This simulates the time taken to pull the data from the data source.

GetAllAccountsPrivateAsync then returns the data and in turn this data is passed back to the caller of the GetAllAccountsAsync endpoint.

Is there any benefit to this approach that I'm missing? In Swagger this still takes 10 seconds for the request to complete, and I'm adding the co-ordination overhead for a process that is essentially synchronous.

I understand using it in cases where you're awaiting data from multiple sources and want to await completion of all queries before combining the results into one output, but when it's pulling data from one source and awaiting completion it seems more efficient to do this synchronously.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("accounts")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Account>> GetAllAccountsAsync()
{
    var accounts = await this.GetAllAccountsPrivateAsync();
    return accounts;
}

private async Task<List<Account>> GetAllAccountsPrivateAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);

    var accounts = new List<Account>
    {
        new Account
        {
            AccountId = 1,
            AccountBalance = 17,
            AccountOwnerName = "Bob"
        },
        new Account
        {
            AccountId = 2,
            AccountBalance = 25,
            AccountOwnerName = "Josie"
        }
    };

    return accounts;
}
```

Comment: This will probably be closed as opinion based.  The benefit of async programming is realised when the server processes many requests at the same time, you'll probably never see the benefit when using just one request.  Also, you're delaying the task for 10 seconds, of course the request will take 10 seconds. Did you expect async to make it quicker?  It just means that if another request comes in, that thread can do something else until the awaited request completes

Comment: I'm not expecting it to be quicker, but I'm trying to see if this actually has any impact whatsoever. Is there a way to measure how much of a difference this makes in scaling? I've read around this topic a fair amount and I've not found anything conclusive / measurable to show this is the best approach.

Comment: You are going to need to learn a bit more about the what, where, and why, check out [microsofts guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: In order to measure a difference you'd need two things: 1) real I/O-bound flows (not a `Task.Delay`) and 2) a tool which can produce and measure the ability to scale by increasing the load (you can tailor your own or use existing one like JMeter or Gattling). Note that the load factor (number of requests per some period of time - second, millisecond, etc.) is important as it allows to utilize I/O bandwidth, which is key salability factor, but remember that low load may not give any benefits as bandwidth can be underutilized while high load can cause degradation due to over-utilized bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Async allows the application to manage its thread pool, managing concurrency and new request can be handled more efficiently.

Read More: [Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Also Check: [Advanced Tips for Using Task.Run With Async/Await](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/advanced-tips-using-task-run-async-wait)